# How to create a click-function in a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Hey I am new to js and I was trying to open a bootstrap modal with a click on a button (I set the id to the value of the button because the id comes from a database) and if you click on "yes" in that modal a click function should be triggered which should then delete the selected row.

I am able to open the modal and setting the id also works but if I click the yes button in the modal there is no alert...

This is the modal located in content.html:

```
<!--Delete Modal-->
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Return Device</h3>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col">
                            <p><b> Are you sure you want to return this device? </b></p>
                            Please make sure you return the device.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary delBtn" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my JS located in main.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#myInput').trigger('focus');
});

  $('#booked').click(function () {
    $('#changestuff').load('content.html #booked', function () {
        register();
        change();
        $('.ret').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).val();
            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        })
        returnOne(id, tr);
    });

    $('#booked').addClass('active');
    $('#book').removeClass('active');
    $('#admin').removeClass('active');

});
});

function returnOne(id, tr)
{
        $('.delBtn').click(function () {

    alert("you returned" +id);

})
}
```

Where is my error? I think it might be because the modal hasn't been loaded when I try to get the click event but I'm not sure. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are binding click event again and again from inside returnOne function and it may happen that button DOM not created. Do you need both id and tr inside Yes button click handler?

Comment: the yes button is the one with class "delbtn", the one where the id and tr are set is the button that calls the modal.
Or did you mean the parameters for the function "returnone"? in that case yes we do need it because they will be used for later use.

Comment: I have provided solution, which you can use to get id on click of Yes button. Also, you can get tr to be deleted. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

click event handler is not attaching may be it is getting called before yes button dom get created. 
Try below code where you can store row to be deleted in a variable and set `row-id` data attribute on Yes button. In click handler of Yes button, read the id and you can delete row from variable `rowToDelete`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var rowToDelete;

    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        $('#myInput').trigger('focus');
    });

    /*$('#changestuff').load('content.html #book', function(){
        register();
        change();
        getChosenDevices();

    });*/

    $('#changestuff').on('load','content.html #book', function(){
        register();
        change();
        getChosenDevices();

    });

    $('#booked').click(function() {
        $('#booked').addClass('active');
        $('#book').removeClass('active');
        $('#admin').removeClass('active');
    });

    $(document).on('click','.ret',function() {
                var id = $(this).val();
                $('#deleteModal .delBtn').data('row-id', id); //set data id
                rowToDelete = $(this).closest('tr'); //store row in variable
     });

    $(document).on("click", '#deleteModal button.delBtn', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var rowId = $(this).data('row-id');
        alert("you returned" + rowId);
        $('#deleteModal').modal('toggle');
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/u7ofjprw/77/)

Comment: Works partcially the functions on top work out fine but this part does not get triggered when I click on the yes btn(Tried it with an alert...):

        $("#myModal").on("click",'.delBtn',function () {
        var rowId = $(this).data('row-id');
        alert("you returned" +rowId);
    })
(sorry don't know how to formate code in an comment...)

Comment: are you creating `#myModal` dynamically?

Comment: to be honest I don't know I just did it like in the bootstrap turtorials...

Comment: ok, on safer side we can handle it as dyncamically created element. see my updated post where i have delegated click event using document for Yes button

Comment: I updated my code but it still has the same problem I am not getting into the clickfunction by clicking on yes :(

Comment: can you remove `data-dismiss="modal"` from Yes button and put `$('#myModal').modal('toggle');` inside yes button click handler and try

Comment: changed it but still the click yes btn function gets not triggered

Comment: can you recreate this issue on jsfiddle or code snippet? See this for reference http://jsfiddle.net/gx97spa1/

Comment: I tried to get my code run but I am not even able to get my code right into the fiddle that the error appears this may take a while until my fiddle runs to show the real issue...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/u7ofjprw/33/ this is the best i got sorry if it is trash i tried my best

Comment: After looking at your jsfiddle i found that `.load()` function is not available in jquery 3.3.1, there is extra `});` and i have put `#myModal` instead of `#deleteModal` as Yes button is from deleteModal. After commenting `load` and write it with `.on('load'..` it is working, please see my updated post